# Where did the old object go?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I've implemented a routine to sort an xhtml table in place that is based on (= more or less copied from) Nicholas C. Zakas, *Professional JavaScript for Web Developers*, Ch. 12. It works as advertised, but I have a few questions about how the code works and would be grateful for advice. Here are the relevant bits:

```
var oldTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
var oldTableBody = oldTable.tBodies[0];
var oldTableRows = oldTableBody.rows;
var newTableArray = new Array();
for (var i = 0, rowCount = oldTableRows.length; i < rowCount; i++) {
    newTableArray.push(oldTableRows[i]);
}
newTableArray.sort(chooseSort);
var newFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0, rowCount = newTableArray.length; i < rowCount; i++) {
    newFragment.appendChild(newTableArray[i]);
}
oldTableBody.appendChild(newFragment);
```

I understand that I'm adding pointers to the existing table rows when I push new values onto `newTableArray`, but I'm not sure how the `appendChild` methods work. Specifically:

1. When I append each of the array items (pointers to the original rows) to the document fragment, am I just adding a pointer (leaving the row still in the original table), or am I removing the row object from the original table by appending it somewhere else?
2. When I append `newFragment` to `oldTableBody`, if I understand correctly, I'm actually appending not the fragment as an object, but the row objects that I've appended to it, and that's just the way fragments work. Is that correct?
3. When I append `newFragment` to `oldTableBody`, I don't do anything explicit to remove the rows that were originally there. Where did they go? Does appending them anew automatically remove any old traces of them because they can be attached only once? If I'm working with pointers, and not the objects themselves (which I thought was what let me attach them to `newTableArray` without automatically making them disappear from the table), does this mean that I can have multiple pointers to the same object in some cases (`oldTable` plus `newTableArray`) but not others (original rows in the original table plus the new, sorted rows that I'm adding)?

Apologies for the naive questions, but although getting the results that I want is satisfying, not understanding how the code works makes me uneasy.

Answer (score 1):

I think all your questions boil down to asking what `appendChild` does.  It removes the element from where it was in the DOM and places the ***same*** element in the new spot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your second assertion is correct. You're not creating a pointer, but rather relocating the object into the document fragment.
2. Your understanding of documenty fragments is correct. It is a generic container that never becomes part of the DOM. Rather its content is appended.
3. Relates to item one. You removed them from the table when appending them to the fragment. When adding them to the Array, it is just a pointer to the Row Objects getting added. Adding elements to an Array does nothing to manipulate the DOM itself.

As such, your code is ultimately:

- doing an iteration to reference each table row into an Array
- doing an iteration over the Array to relocate each row into a document fragment
- appending the content of the fragment into the original table

...resulting in no noticeable change to the DOM.

If you were hoping to duplicate the rows, you may be interested in the `.cloneNode()` method.

But no, you can't have a single element appear in several different places in the DOM in such a manner that an update to the element in one location will be reflected in other locations.